# Daisy chained second monitor missing after switching inputs on the monitor

Tags: thunderbolt, daisychaining

I've tested the following setup for a presentation room:

An HDMI-device is connected to the DP-IN of a monitor via an active HDMI -> DP-cable.
A notebook or tablet is connected via USB-C to the same monitor.
A projector is connected to the DP-OUT of the monitor via an active DP -> HDMI-cable.

The reason I'm not being very specific with the devices is that I ran into the exact same issue with a multitude of different devices.

1. When I hook an iPad Air to the monitor's USB-C-input, I can happily switch back and forth between the iPad and the HDMI-device on the monitor and both are mirrored perfectly fine on the monitor and the projector. (Which is exactly what I want!)
2. When I hook a notebook with only DP-Alt-Mode (no Thunderbolt!) to the monitor's USB-C-input, I can switch happily back and forth between the HDMI-device (mirrored on monitor and projector) and the notebook (MST, the monitor extends, the projector mirrors the notebooks screen. Again, this is exactly what I want.)

So far, so happy me.

3. When I try 2. with any Thunderbolt-notebook, I can switch exactly once between inputs and after that, upon switching back to the notebook, I permanently lose connection to the projector. This is consistent among various notebooks and monitors. The only way to reconnect to the projector is to manually reconnect the DP -> HDMI-cable. (One exception being a Samsung monitor that actually features a working HDMI-passthrough to DP-OUT! Sadly, you have to dig pretty deep into the monitor's menu to switch in- and outputs. Also, the Dell P2422HE seems to work fine after the latest FW-Update. Other, very similarly built Dell monitors show the exact same bug as described above.)

I know I'm bending the daisy-chaining feature "a little" here, but I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't work with TB specifically. Also, the setup is very tempting for me, because it would be waaaaaay simpler than the alternative of using a monitor, a seperate dockingstation and an HDMI-switch to do the same job as quite a few monitors can do on their own. (Less cables, less power supplies, only one device to interact with.)

I'd greatly appreciate any input on this, even if it only leads to me unterstanding why this won't ever work properly. (Of course, I'd be happier if this was fixable.)

Thanks!